# PHP File Upload Script is not writing to temp directory

Tags: php

Alright, so I am having an issue with my image uploading script/application. I have tried debugging time after time again and still cannot find out what the issue is. The code seems to be fine, but for some reason or another the file looks like it's not get saved in the temp directory so that it can then moved over to my uploads directory on my server. I have made certain that the directory(uploads) that i'm trying to upload it to, including the temp directory, have read/write/execute permissions set and that uploads is set to on in the php.ini folder. I have a feeling that the files are never getting saved to the temp folder, but i'm not sure how to check if that is the case, since i understand the file is deleted after the script finishes executing. I hope you guys can help me out, because I have no clue what to do. There's the code for my script.

Also, this is where my issue is located at.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($filetempname)) {
          $final = "../public_html/uploads/" . $filename;              
          $result = move_uploaded_file($filetempname, $final);
          if($result)
          {
            echo 'success';
            echo "<br>Stored in: " . "public_html/uploads/" . $filename;
          }
          else
          {
            echo 'Image was not uploaded.';
          }
```

$result= move_uploaded_file($filetempname, $final) keeps returning false with no sign of an error occuring. I know that if the file type is not correct it'll return false and won't do copy anything and also it'll return false if the file cannot be moved for some reason and it will raise an alert message saying that. However, I'm not having a message raised at all. All I know is that it returns false and it doesn't do what it should do.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($_FILES);
$filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filetempname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
$error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $filename));
if ((($filetype == "image/gif")
|| ($filetype == "image/jpeg")
|| ($filetype == "image/jpg")
|| ($filetype == "image/pjepg")
|| ($filetype == "image/x-png")
|| ($filetype == "image/png"))
&& ($filesize < 1000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ( $error > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $error . "<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Upload: " . $filename . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $filetype . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($filesize / 1024) . " KB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $filetempname . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("../public_html/uploads/" . $filename)) {
            echo $filename . " already exists. ";
        }        
        else {
            if (is_uploaded_file($filetempname)) {
              $final = "../public_html/uploads/" . $filename;              
              $result = move_uploaded_file($filetempname, $final);
              if($result)
              {
                echo 'success';
                echo "<br>Stored in: " . "public_html/uploads/" . $filename;
              }
              else
              {
                echo 'Image was not uploaded.';
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Here's the code for the form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="scripts/snap.php">
        <!--<p>
            <input id="plat" class="plat" name="plat" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input id="plon" class="plon" name="plon" type="hidden" value=""  />
        </p>-->
        <div class="row">
            <label for="file">Select an image to Upload</label><br />
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><!--onchange="fileSelected();"--> 
        </div>
        <div id="filename"></div>
        <div id="fileSize"></div>    
        <div id="fileType"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            <!--<input type="button" onclick="uploadFile()" value="Upload" />-->
        </div>
        <div id="progressNumber"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Might be a typo but `$filetype == "image/pjepg"` should be `$filetype == "image/pjpeg"`

Comment: Permissions correct on `upload` directory?

Comment: yea, i think it is but it really isn't part of my issue. I actually don't even need that. I just haven't removed it from my code yet. but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: yes, i stated above that i made certain that the permissions were set correctly on both the temp and upload directory

Comment: Can you post your script's output?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about all the file type checking and whatever else. Write a **separate script** that has just one responsibility: moving an uploaded file to the place you want to permanently store it. Focus on that **one little part** and get that working.

Once you have the file-moving code working, wrap it in a function and then, only once that part is working, integrate the file-moving code into the rest of what you have.

The overall lesson here is that, when you come across a problem, it's good to have written your code in a modular enough way that it's really quick and easy to tell where, exactly, that problem is.

Also, consider using a framework or library that handles this file uploading work for you, because you're kind of reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: the reason I'm trying to code this instead of using a library or frame work is because this is part of my senior project, so I would like to understand how it works not just get something that's already put together and slap it on to my project and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

first, check if you are submitting correctly. have you included the enctype on your form?

```
<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php'>
```

next, does your code `print_r($_FILES);` return any value or is it null?

if yes, try to check any exisiting file you know on your uploads folder and use `is_file()` because maybe you are specifying an incorrect path.

Edit: there's no problem in the form

Comment: yea i am using the post method and the enctype is set to multipart/form-data. as for the print_r($_FILES); it returns nothing at all not even null.

Comment: can you post the code for the form too? because the if $_FILES is null, the problem might be on the form then..

Comment: hmm.. i suddenly remembered. i think you should print_r($_FILES["file"]["name"]) instead. is it null also?

Comment: No, all it returned was the name of the file that is gonna be uploaded.

Comment: ive checked the code and this certainly is a file permission or wrong path error, do you have a file in the folder you want to copy the uploaded files from? can you do a `print_r(is_file('../public_html/uploads/'.$whatever_file_it_is));` and check the result?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're asking.

Comment: sorry, can you put that code before the `$result = move_uploaded_file($filetempname, $final);` line? just to know if the path is correct.

Comment: yea, i'm not getting anything back at all after inserting that.

Comment: i believe `is_uploaded_file($filetempname)` is returning false that's why. can you verify this? and also, as i told you earlier, when i debug i tend to do this. create a dummy file on /public/uploads/ folder for example test.txt and check if it exists on your php script.. `file_exists("../public_html/uploads/test.txt" )` if it does, then you can verify the path is correct and narrow down the possible problems

Comment: if is_upload_file($filetempname) was returning false i would never have echo 'image was not uploaded.'; display, so i know it is returning true since it goes into the code and goes into the else statement of the if($result). if($result) is where it is returning false, but I'll try putting that dummy file and checking whether the path is correct.

Comment: yeah. could be the path. plus, is the folder 755? or is it writeable? another problem could be that apache is the user executing php, and does not have the same group as your ftp username

Comment: i'm not getting a value back. should i have put that in an if statement like this? if (file_exists("../public_html/uploads/test.txt"))
{
 echo "yes";
}

Comment: well the folder is acutally 777 and I'm also not using apache, i'm using nginx.

Comment: its easier like this: `print_r(file_exists("../public_html/uploads/test.txt"));` this should return a boolean true or false

Comment: yea, i'm getting nothing back from that print_r

Comment: try adding `exit();` after it just to debug. also, `is_file()` would be better than `file_exists()` i think.

Comment: Once again i'm still getting no feedback. *sigh*....i think i might just ditch this way of making a file upload and go for a framework or library. Nothing seems to be working.